# Showing project dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any easy way of showing project dependencies in Eclipse?

I have 40 or so projects in my workspace. I want to look at one project, and i want to see where the classes of this project are being used in other projects. Is there any way of doing this? I thought using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on the project folder work, but it doesnt seem to. I have to go through each individual package in the project and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get an idea, which is timeconsuming.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly searching using Google I found https://code.google.com/p/epdv/.

Comment: thanks. Its very cool! Do you know how to save a diagram once you create it?